# Why local non-final variable affects the referenced field? Java

Tags: java, reference, pass-by-reference

I have following code in my program:

```
...
private void generateStack() {
    List<AdvertisementsModel> adsForModel = Storage.getAdsForId(model.getId());
    ...
    adsForModel.clear();
...
```

`Storage` is static class with static fields and methods. `generateStack` method is in another class and in instance object. Why does `adsForModel.clear();` affects the list in `Storage` class if `asdForModel` reference is not final?

Comment: If it is final, is the original list not affected? I have doubts about that... It's the same list instance. for this, I'd use either `new ArrayList<AdvertisementsModel>(Storage.getAdsForId(model.getId()));`, which creates a new instance and if possible, modified the `Storage` class to return an UnmofifiableList of the original list.

Comment: using `final` on a list will only make the list reference immutable not the list content

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy, very good note, thnank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Storage.getAdsForId(...)` returns a copy of the reference to the same `List` object. So calls via this reference effect the same list. When you call `Storage.getAdsForId` there is no new List created - just a new reference to the same list.

Therefore it's good practise to either return explicitly `ImmutableList` or making a defensive copy of the list in `Storage.getAdsForId(...)` and returning the copy.

Be aware that you need to make a deep copy when `AdvertisementsModel` is mutable or you'll run into the same problem on a different level. (Otherwise you may have a list copy now but both lists still containing references to the same `AdvertisementsModel` objects and changing them still effect the list contents inside `Storage`.)

Answer (score 3):

Java is pass by value (of the reference).  So, if `Storage.getAdsForId(model.getId())` returns a reference which is staticly stored within Storage then calling `clear()` on it in the instance will affect the same List within `Storage` as well.  You could do this instead:

```
return new ArrayList<AdvertisementsModel>(Storage.getAdsForId(model.getId()));
```

to return a copy of the list instead which would avoid affecting the list within Storage. Of course, modifying an element of this list will still affect the same element present within the list in `Storage`.  To avoid that, you'd have to deep copy each element in the list.

Comment: Why copy, rather than wrapping using Collections.unmodifiableList to wrap the original list?

Comment: Well, for one, you wouldn't be able to cal the clear() method on it (as posted in the code above).

Answer (score 1):

`getAdsForId` should return a copy of the list, otherwise it will return a reference and calling `clear` on the list will empty the original one.

Answer (score 1):

If it is final, is the original list not affected? I have doubts about that... It's the same list instance. For this, I'd use either

```
new ArrayList<AdvertisementsModel>(Storage.getAdsForId(model.getId()));
```

which creates a new list instance and if possible, modified the `Storage` class to return an UnmofifiableList of the original list:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(adsForIdList);
```

I'd prefer this, as this solution does not create a new List instance with each call, it is the responsibility of the receiving code to decide if that needs to be created or not. However, in multithreaded environments, if the original list might be modified, this might result in `ConcurrentModificationException`s - so in that case it is wiser to create a "defensive copy" of the list in the getter itself. Be sure to keep in mind, that then the modifications to the copy will not affect the original list...